# Basic Page content wont display Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I recently started using Drupal 8. I am able to add a basic page, but whenever I try to view it, the body text pertaining to the page does not display, only the page title is visible. Does anybody have any ideas as to why I am experiencing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Attached is a screenshot of where I am expecting to see the body text for the page. The title of the post is visible, but not the body

[image]

Comment: From what I have read, it feels like the problem has something to do with the user permissions.

Comment: So what have you done so far ? Which user/role encounter this issue ? How is configured your content display for that field ? Do you still have the issue when switching theme ? Is there any error logged ?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. It is a fresh install of Drupal running on a local Apache server. I tried creating a administrator role and checking all the Permissions fields, but I can still only see the title of the post when I try view it. At the moment I am just using the default theme, there are also no errors logged as far as I can tell. I have attached a screenshot to my post of where I am expecting to view the body text.

Comment: Check the body display settings https://www.drupal.org/node/1577708. I would also check database to see if the body was submitted correctly, an error during form submit could prevent this after passing validation thus without error messages (but you can still check php logs). Also, I would use the real admin user (user 1) to avoid dealing with permission issue, that said, if you see any change, it means it IS a permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have disabled the body field display from content type settings. Go to the page 'your site address/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display' and check the body field is disabled or not. If disabled please enable it for showing the content on front end.